# Width of cells of table

Tags: html, css

Why does a table with 2 cells, one is an image and the other is text. When I change the text length it affect the size of the image?

There's a code with 2 tables that the text length is different so the image is different.

```
<body>

<div id="more-time2" class="very-small-text-size more-time " index="2" mode="Available" onclick="toggle(this.getAttribute('index'), this.getAttribute('mode'))">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td id="arr-icon2" class="accordion_down"> </td>
            <td id="more-time-text2" class="more-time-button" index="2">more more more time</td>
    </table>
</div>

    <div id="more-time2" class="very-small-text-size more-time " index="2" mode="Available" onclick="toggle(this.getAttribute('index'), this.getAttribute('mode'))">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td id="arr-icon22" class="accordion_down"> </td>
            <td id="more-time-text2" class="more-time-button" index="2">more time</td>
    </table>
</div>
```

```
    body
    {
        direction:rtl;
    }
    .more-time {
        display: table;
        width: 100%;
        color: dodgerblue
    }

    td.accordion_down {
        background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,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');
        width: 12%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: contain;
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
        background-position: center;
    }

    td.more-time-button {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
        padding-right: 4%;
        padding: 0.25% 0;
    }
```

And [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2a243eme/2/) link.

Why does it happen?

Comment: because you have this css property in td.accordion_down; background-size: contain;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because in `td.accordion_down` you give a 12% width to the image and it scales based on the parent container, just give a fixed width (based on what you need) like:

```
td.accordion_down {
        background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,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');
        width: 50px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: contain;
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
        background-position: center;
    }
```

Comment: I didn't want it to be fixed because the screen size can be various and I don't want it to be big in some and too small in others

Comment: @Dror yeah but your solution doesn't scale with the screen resolution and also those kind of icons keeps their sizes the same almost everytime, if you want to change the size based on the screen size you can just create a js that on screen resize changes the background-image: url to a smaller or bigger image